# Android: Unable to create PDFRenderer

Tags: android, pdf, document, pdfrenderer

I am currently having problem create PDFRenderer object. I have a pdf file inside the assets folder and using getAssets().openfd to get the file descriptor.

My code creating the object is:

```
try {
        _fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd(assetFile).getParcelFileDescriptor();
        _pdfRender = new PdfRenderer(_fileDescriptor);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The error saying : java.io.IOException: not create document.  The fileDescriptor isn't null and the assetFile has a correct file path.

I am using the correct android api 21. I tried using lower version android but force close so I think not the phone problem

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes .. now I am downloading pdf and saved in local ...